# Bootstrap's 3 Collapse on button click in Thymeleaf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I am trying to implement a simple Bootstrap 3 collapse element in Thymeleaf on button click. I did the following:

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" th:attr="data-target='#demo'">click</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
   hello
</div>
```

However, clicking on button does nothing, despite including Bootstrap's js and css files.  Is the syntax I'm using correct?

Answer (score 1):

yes your syntax is wrong.

Remote th:Attr from your html.it must be like this

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">click</button>
```

[More Detail](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)  I am using Thymeleaf which has specific syntax in addition to Bootstrap's, hence my confusion.  I tried using just the Bootstrap syntax, but that did not work either :(